# Angular 2 - pass check box selection

Tags: angular

I'm facing a bit confusion with check box and validating a field in Angular 2. I'm trying to do custom validation for textfield. And textfield validation is based on check box selection. There are three check boxes,like checkbox1,2,3. Here I just need to know checkbox2 selected or not and if selected I need to pass a boolean flag to validate a text field.

So for that I have written a change method and calling in that particular check box like this.

```html
<div class="bx--row">
    <div>
        <label  class="bx--label">select your options:</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="bx--checkbox-input" 
               type="checkbox" 
               name="ch1"  
               formControlName="yourOption">
        <label for="ch1" class="bx--label">checkbox1</label>
     </div> 
     <div>
         <input class="bx--checkbox-input"  
                type="checkbox" 
                name="ch2" 
                (change)="checkSelection()" 
                formControlName="yourOption">
         <label for="ch2" class="bx--label">checkbox2</label>
      </div>  
      <div>
          <input class="bx--checkbox-input"  
                 type="checkbox" name="ch3"  
                 formControlName="yourOption" >
          <label for="ch3" class="bx--label">chekbox3</label>
      </div>             
 </div>
```

This is my .ts file, which I'm declared boolean flag and calling change method and passing boolean flag to customvalidator parameter.

```js
checkOption = false;
checkboxSelection(){
    this.checkOption = this.formGroupCheckbox.controls['youroption'].value;
    console.log(this.checkOption);
};

formGroupCheckbox(){
    'textfield': new FormControl('', [customvalidator.validateField(this.checkOption);
}
```

Problem: When I'm trying to pass boolean flag always sending false only, even though checkbox selected also. But if I console in checkboxSelection() method there my boolean value getting changing according to selection. But I'm not sure whether this process correct or not, Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that when calling `formGroupCheckbox()` function `checkOption` value is set to false. So your validator function has `false` value when textfield control is created. It happens because your `checkOption` property is value type. To avoid this you should pass youroption control reference, so your validator function can access **actual** control's value.

Instead of that try to pass whole `youroption` control there. Try:

```
new FormControl('', [customvalidator.validateField(this.formGroupCheckbox.controls['youroption'])])
```

And then in `customvalidator`:

```
validateField(checkboxControl: AbstractControl): ValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
          // You can access actual checkbox value with checkboxControl.value
          // Here you should write your custom validation logic
        };
      }
```